# CSOM Item Level Security "Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection."

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am trying to create an app that will set item level security for certain items in a library.  However, I am getting the error mentioned above after these lines:

```
item.RoleAssignments.Add( grp, roleDefBinding );
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323987/cannot-add-a-role-assignment-with-empty-role-definition-binding-collection) question on Stack Overflow, and tried to copy the code, with some changes.  Here is the full code:

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext( Context );
using ( var ctx = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost() )
{
    Web w = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load( w, web=> web.SiteGroups, web=>web.RoleDefinitions );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    List list = w.Lists.GetById( Guid.Parse( ddlLibraries.SelectedItem.Value ) );
    ctx.Load(list);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    String 
        roleNameStr = ddlPermissions.SelectedItem.Text,
        grpName = ddlBUs.SelectedItem.Text;

    var role = w.RoleDefinitions.Where( r => r.Name == roleNameStr );
    if ( role.Count() > 0 )
    {
        RoleDefinition roleDef = role.First();
        var group = w.SiteGroups.Where( g => g.Title == grpName );
        if ( group.Count() > 0 )
        {
            RoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection( ctx );
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            roleDefBinding.Add( roleDef );

            Group grp = group.First() as Group;

            CamlQuery query;
            query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems( query );
            ctx.Load( items );
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach ( Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items )
            {
                ctx.Load( item, i=>i.RoleAssignments, i=>i.HasUniqueRoleAssignments );
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                if ( !item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments )
                {
                    item.BreakRoleInheritance( true, false );
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                item.RoleAssignments.Add( grp, roleDefBinding );
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any errors in my code, or something I am missing?  Not sure if it makes a difference, but this is an Office 365 environment.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be the `ExecuteQuery` you call right after you create `RoleDefinitionBindingCollection`.

This code should work:

```
static void BreakInheritanceAndSetRoleAssignmentByGroupOnItems(ClientContext clientContext, 
    Web web, string roleName, string groupTitle, List<ListItem> items)
{
    var role = web.RoleDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
    if (role == null) return;

    var group = web.SiteGroups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Title == groupTitle);
    if (group == null) return;

    var roleDefBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext) {role};

    items.ForEach(item =>
    {
        if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
        }
        item.RoleAssignments.Add(group, roleDefBinding);
    });
}
```

Note that it does not call `ExecuteQuery` at all, which is a good thing. But it also expects your `Web` to contain the correct values, as well as items.
Example usage:

```
var web = ctx.Web;
var items = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test").GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items, collection => collection.Include(item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));
ctx.Load(web, w=> w.SiteGroups.Include(sg => sg.Title), w=> w.RoleDefinitions.Include(rd => rd.Name));

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

const string roleName = "Edit"; 
const string groupName = "MyGroup"; 

BreakInheritanceAndSetRoleAssignmentByGroupOnItems(ctx, web, roleName, groupName, items.ToList());
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Note that this will not remove the existing permissions. If you want to do that you could do something like `item => item.RoleAssignments` when loading items and then calling `item.RoleAssignments.ToList().ForEach(ra => ra.DeleteObject());` where you call `BreakRoleInheritance`

Comment: This worked.  I'm still new to CSOM, and still a bit confused when to call `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()`.  Thank you.